# How to filter by hostname instead of instance_id for google stackdriver logging?

Tags: linux, logging, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am setting up the Google Stackdriver logging agent on AWS EC2 instances and in the log viewer I'm only seeing the instance_id's. I would like to be able to filter by hostname instead of instance_id. I have checked all google-fluentd config on the instances and don't see where I can change from instance_id to hostname.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like searching for the hostname isn't an option based on this [article](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_gce_instance). If you would like this feature to be enabled in the future, I would suggest filling an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com).